# When was the surface temperature of the Sun first measured?

Tags: astronomy

William Herschel thought that the Sun was inhabited as did others at that time.  Presumably there was no knowledge of its surface temperature, so when was it first realised that the surface was far too hot for Life to exist there?

Comment: See [this post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3412/who-determined-the-temperature-of-the-sun-first)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who determined the temperature of the Sun first?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3412/who-determined-the-temperature-of-the-sun-first)